# MySQL group by all columns except one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a (cleaner?) way to do the following:

Let's say I have a table, main, with ~15 columns that looks something like this, with one row per id:

```
main:
id      start           end             col4    ...     col15
666     2014-01-01      2014-06-30      ...     ...     ...
1234    2015-03-05      2015-05-02      ...     ...     ...
9876    2014-09-01      2015-01-01      ...     ...     ...
...(etc)
```

Then I have another table, events, which may have 0, 1, or many rows per id:

```
events:
id      date            code
666     2014-01-20      "code_a"
1234    2015-05-01      "code_b"
666     2014-01-25      "code_c"
666     2014-02-09      "code_z"
... (etc)
```

and finally I have a table, codes, which has one row per code, giving a description for the code as well as a type (0,1, or 2):

```
codes:
code            desc            type
"code_a"        "something"     0 
"code_b"        "somethn else"  1
"code_c"        "another thing" 0
"code_d"        "one more"      2
(no code z)
```

and what I want as a result is main's 15 columns plus three additional columns which contain comma separated lists of event codes which happened between the start and end dates for that id by type (first column is type 0, second type 1, third type 2), so:

```
id      start           end             ...     col15   type_0          type_1  type_2
666     2014-01-01      2014-06-30      ...     ...     "code_a,code_c"         
1234    2015-03-05      2015-05-02      ...     ...                     "code_b"
...(etc)
```

my solution is

```
select m.*
     , group_concat(c0.code) as type_0
     , group_concat(c1.code) as type_1
     , group_concat(c2.code) as type_2
from main m 
     left join events e on m.id = e.id and e.date between m.start and m.end
     left join codes c0 on c0.code = e.code and c0.type = 0
     left join codes c1 on c1.code = e.code and c1.type = 1
     left join codes c2 on c2.code = e.code and c2.type = 2
group by m.id
       , m.start
       , m.end
       , m.col4
       , m.col5
       , m.col6
       , m.col7
       , m.col8
       , m.col9
       , m.col10
       , m.col11
       , m.col12
       , m.col13
       , m.col14
       , m.col15
```

But to me that's pretty nasty looking. Is there a more elegant way to do this (especially avoiding the 15 columns listed in the group by)?

Comment: Shoot. I'm sure it's clear but the joins to c1 and c2 should say c1.code, c1.type and c2.code, c2.type respectively.

Comment: You know you can edit your own question?

Comment: does your query runs at all? I doubt so cause of your `group_concat`

Comment: Didn't see the edit button. Fixed the column in group_concats and the table names in the joins.

@Rahul it's a simplified version of the real problem involving longer table names and column names...

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can just use `GROUP BY m.id`. Unless you enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option, it allows you to use non-aggregate columns that aren't in the `GROUP BY` clause. This could produce unprectable results if you selected columns that were not uniquely identified by the grouping column, but that's not the case here -- you're grouping by a column that's the unique ID for the `m` table, and all the non-aggregate columns are from that same table.

In strict SQL, you would have to do it by doing the `GROUP_CONCAT`s in a subquery, which you then join with the `main` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT m.id,
            , group_concat(c0.code) as type_0
            , group_concat(c1.code) as type_1
            , group_concat(c2.code) as type_2
     FROM main m
     left join events e on m.id = e.id and e.date between m.start and m.end
     left join codes c0 on c0.code = e.code and c0.type = 0
     left join codes c1 on c1.code = e.code and c1.type = 1
     left join codes c2 on c2.code = e.code and c2.type = 2
     GROUP BY m.id
) t1
JOIN main m ON t1.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 1):

With the "one row per id" specification, you can take advantage of the MySQL extension to the `GROUP BY` which allows you to include non-aggregates in the SELECT list. The only change required to your query would be to just

```
 GROUP BY m.id
```

Other databases would throw an error with that. We can get MySQL to throw an error too, if we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode` for the session.

---

Another alternative would be to avoid a `GROUP BY` operation on `m`, using an inline view. You still need to do a `GROUP BY`, but you can do that in the inline view, where the other columns from `main` aren't returned, we only return the unique `id` value. We need that for the join in the outer query.

Also seems like you only need one join to the `codes` table; you could use a conditional test inside the GROUP_CONCAT to conditionally return the value of the code.

For example:

```
SELECT m.*
     , g.type_0
     , g.type_1
     , g.type_2
  FROM main m
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT a.id
              , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type=0,c.code,NULL)) AS type_0
              , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type=1,c.code,NULL)) AS type_1
              , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type=2,c.code,NULL)) AS type_2
           FROM main a
           LEFT
           JOIN events e
             ON e.id = a.id
            AND e.date BETWEEN a.start AND a.end
           LEFT
           JOIN codes c
             ON c.code = e.code
            AND c.type IN (0,1,2)
          GROUP BY a.id
       ) g
    ON g.id = m.id
```

I'm not sure that either of those qualifies as "a more elegant way" or not. (Both of these depend on the `id` column being UNIQUE in `main`. The second query also relies on `id` being non-NULL.)

You might want to consider adding an `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`, for a more deterministic result. It's also possible to include the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `GROUP_CONCAT`, if there's no reason to return "duplicate" values of `code` in the list, e.g.

```
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(c.type=0,c.code,NULL) ORDER BY 1)\
```

Also be aware that the maximum length of the value returned from `GROUP_CONCAT` is limited to `group_concat_max_len`.

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter version would be like below by getting the grouping first and then join with it.

```
select m.*
     , XX.type_0
     , XX.type_1
     , XX.type_2
from main m 
     left join events e on m.id = e.id and e.date between m.start and m.end
     left join (
select code, GROUP_CONCAT(case when type = 0 then code else null end SEPARATOR ', ') AS type_0,
GROUP_CONCAT(case when type = 1 then code else null end SEPARATOR ', ') AS type_1,
GROUP_CONCAT(case when type = 2 then code else null end SEPARATOR ', ') AS type_2
from codes 
group by <some_column> )XX ON XX.code = e.code;
```